# How to get top 400 lists from iTunes

Tags: app-store, itunes

How do I get the top 400 (or more) lists for apps from iTunes? I need the top paid, free, and grossing lists for each category and overall.

I know the rss feed exists, at https://rss.itunes.apple.com/ but that only gives you the top 200. Yet sites like AppFigures and AppAnnie have lists of the top 400 or 500, and apps in the app store will show you the top 400.

I tried the EPF feed, the popularity table only has twenty rows on it, and from other forums it looks like that feed has been unavailable for months, and it doesn't update as often as these other sites seem to anyway.

I am looking for a solution directly from Apple, not via a third party. I am 99% certain that Apple provides this data hourly, but I do not know the endpoint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you do it.... you can hit a URL as follows and supply an iOS5 user agent.

```
_IOS_DEEP_RANK_URL_BASE = 'https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/topChartFragmentData?genreId=%s&popId=%s&pageNumbers=%d&pageSize=%d'

_IOS_DEEP_RANK_USERAGENT =  'iTunes-iPad/5.1.1 (64GB; dt:28)'
```

You need to set the store front too, based on what country you want.

```
"X-Apple-Store-Front: 143441-1,9"
```

Comment: Interesting - do you need a jailbroken device, or any device with older iOS version will do? Seems to me like a really hacky and unreliable solution - it sounds a bit like decrypting the iTunes traffic using a key. I remember that Apple recently limited their chart in the appstore on devices to top 150 (if i remember correctly), how do you get 1000? Please elaborate - BTW, Apple did not respond to me anymore when I asked for alternatives to the notorious table we discussed.

Comment: @PlamenPetrov   From Apple: 'Legacy (WebObjects) Links

These links have been around since the inception of the iTunes Store, are still supported, and will be indefinitely. The preferred host for these links is now “itunes.apple.com,” but “phobos.apple.com” links are also still supported.'  https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/linking-to-the-itunes-music-store/#Legacy You don't need a jailbroken device you can specify that user-agent header in making your request

Comment: @PlamenPetrov Also look at the parameters in the request.  'pageNumbers' & 'pageSize'. If you do pageNumbers=0 and pageSize=1500 you can get up to 1500 apps

Comment: @CharltonProvatas this answer is now kind of old - 30 months. Things might have changed.

Comment: @PlamenPetrov I can confirm that this endpoint does work using Postman (not necessarily jailbroken device).  In fact, the user agent header isn't required.  Updating the popId will show iPhone/iPad paid/free/grossing etc.  The only thing it doesn't support to my knowledge are dates.

Answer (score 11):

**Update 12 October 2015**: According to Apple Developer Support as of 9th October 2015 the issue has been resolved.

---

RSS feeds are indeed currently capped at 200 results (although they have been set to max 400 in the past),

Regarding the EPF relational - some services (e.g. Chomp) have relied on it in the past. I'm not sure about its current status, but if you've tried to use it make sure you get the full weekly release (which size-wise must be in the range of over 5 GBs), not just an increment release. Maybe this is the reason you get just a few rows?

Currently I don't know of other ways to get this information from Apple directly. You may try a free service from [f6s](http://www.f6s.com/moglobe) or use an API provided by another paid service.

**Update - Apple feedback received**:

This is an interesting topic for me, so I contacted Apple yesterday and asked them  is there any way to retrieve this data directly from them. This morning I received feedback on the availability of chart data from the iTunes  Affiliate team at Apple. They confirmed the limitations of the RSS feed and also said the following on the EPF question:

> If you are an affiliate, you could look into the EPF Relational to develop your own search results.
>
> The EPF is a multiple-gigabyte download of the complete set of
>   metadata from the iTunes Store, App Store, and Mac App Store. EPF is
>   available for affiliates to fully incorporate aspects of the iTunes
>   and App Store catalogs into a website or app. This tool is only for
>   tech-savvy affiliates, and knowledge of relational databases setup is
>   required. Apple will not provide technical support for setting up or
>   maintaining this tool.
>
> EPF access is only available for approved Affiliate Program
>   publishers. More information regarding the EPF can be found on the
>   Enterprise Partner Feed documentation page. Review the documentation
>   found there, and if you would then like access to the EPF, provide the
>   following information: ...

Upon further investigation of the [ERPF technical documentation](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed.html#overview) I found out that one of the tables in the database contains the top 1000 applications by genre:

[image: application popularity table]

So, you should first import the data in your own database, starting from a weekly (multi-gigabyte) release, and then apply any daily (multi-megabyte) updates available since the weekly release. According to Apple the difference between the two is:

> Feed Modes
>
> iTunes generates the EPF data in two modes:
>
> - full mode
> - incremental mode
>
> The full export is generated weekly and
>   contains a complete snapshot of iTunes metadata as of the day of
>   generation. The incremental export is generated daily and contains
>   records that have been added or modified since the last full export.
>   The incremental exports are located relative to the full export on
>   which they are based.

Provided you've imported the data in a relational database, you should be able to get the needed data with a simple `SELECT` statement similar to this one:

```
SELECT application.title, applicationpopularityper_genre.application_rank 
FROM applicationpopularityper_genre 
JOIN application 
  ON application.application_id = applicationpopularityper_genre.application_id
WHERE applicationpopularityper_genre.genreid = XX
ORDER BY applicationpopularityper_genre.application_rank ASC;
```

Regarding hourly updates - by looking at the relational structure, I see that an `export_date` column is available. You should check if you get multiple dates for each application when executing the select above - if you do, you have data with finer granularity than a day. If not (which is more probable), and this is a dealbreaker for you, you should look at using the services of Appannie and others that I already proposed, that enrich this data with the data they get from developers via itunes connect. If you want the information free, you can try to scrape from Appannie (there are some [free tools](https://github.com/cbchen/app-annie-scraper) that do this, but you should know that this may not be very reliable in the long term, so you may be better off paying);

**Update 2:**

iTunes Affiliate Team confirmed that they are aware of the issue with this table.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: What URL exists where one can scrape this data from Apple, anything beyond the top 200? It seems like Apple doesn't expose a public URL - can you cite such a URL?

Comment: Also, the EPFR feed from Apple can be had by anyone that asks politely, and we have it. It does not seem to contain ranking data, hourly or otherwise.

Comment: I revised my answer since it got downvoted - I removed the part where I explain how many of these services get this information but in summary - their popularity amongst developers helps them collect the data. I believe they are not taking it in bulk from Apple. Anyway, check out the free service I suggested and see if it would work for you, also make sure the EPFR you got is the full one. I'm still waiting on information by a friend of mine, I'll update you in case there is a way to get this info directly that I didn't know of.

Comment: So, I would just say that I'm 99.9% certain Apple provides rankings data, in an hourly fashion. There must be some endpoint for this - does the EPFR come out hourly in any fashion?

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer after feedback I got from Apple. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: It does seem from the docs that the data should be in the EPF feed, but I have downloaded and extracted them. The application_popularity_per_genre data file is only 4k, and when I extract it, it only puts 20 rows in my database. Someone on the apple developer forum says the issue has existed since November,and before that time the table had 5.5 million rows. (https://devforums.apple.com/message/1131742#1131742)

Comment: I also looked at the incremental versions, and in those the popularity download is the same size as the in the full versions, for songs and books as well. I assumed this was because the ranks were just fully updated each day.

Comment: This is rather strange! Make sure you're not looking at some kind of demo-version of the table. Did you manage to check out the bug report that has been filed (19843267 in the Apple bugreporter) - I cannot seem to find it. Maybe it is a bug indeed. I'll check with the Apple affiliate team on this, I hope they answer. I'll update as I get more information.

Comment: It's not a demo version. The rest of the data is complete, and enormous.  I also looked at all of the archives available, they go back about a month. They all had 16-20 rows. I was not able to find that bug report either. I had sent a message the affiliate team too, but I didn't hear back. Hopefully you have better luck with them!

Comment: Let's track the thread in question and see what happens. I'll update you if I get anything new.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to let you know that I have an official confirmation on the issue by Apple (updated my answer at the bottom). They still didn't provide a link where its status can be tracked, and also didn't acknowledge my question for possible alternatives for the time being. I'll report back if I get anything new!

Comment: What about grossing? I haven't found grossing lists in EPF.

Answer (score 3):

Would scraping data from AppAnnie be fine?

Used phantomjs and casperjs to scrape top 500 of free, paid and grossing.

1. Install phantomjs and casperjs in your system
2. In terminal: casperjs appAnnieTop500Scraper.js

> Sample Output

```
Free Apps
500 apps found:
// not shown: app names in json array format
// json array on file: freeTop500.json
Paid Apps
500 apps found:
// not shown: app names in json array format
// json array on file: paidTop500.json
Grossing Apps
500 apps found:
// not shown: app names in json array format
// json array on file: grossingTop500.json
```

> appAnnieTop500Scraper.js

```js
var free = [];
var paid = [];
var grossing = [];

var FREE_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;
var PAID_COLUMN_INDEX = 2;
var GROSSING_COLUMN_INDEX = 3;

var fs = require('fs');
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.on("click", function() {
  this.echo();
});
casper.on("page.error", function() {
  this.echo();
});

function getAppListScraper(columnIndex) {
  var selector = document.querySelectorAll('tbody#storestats-top-table tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ') div.item-info div.main-info span.title-info');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(selector, function(e) {
    return e.getAttribute('title');
  });
}

function printToConsole(casper, appList) {
  casper.echo(appList.length + ' apps found:');
  casper.echo(JSON.stringify(appList));
}

function writeToFile(fileName, content) {
  fs.write(fileName, content, 'w');
}

casper.start('https://www.appannie.com/apps/ios/top/?device=iphone', function() {
  // click load all button to load 500 apps list
  this.click('div#load-more-box span.btn-load p a.load-all');

  // wait 5000ms for the apps list to load then scrape it
  this.wait(5000, function() {
    free = this.evaluate(getAppListScraper, FREE_COLUMN_INDEX);
    paid = this.evaluate(getAppListScraper, PAID_COLUMN_INDEX);
    grossing = this.evaluate(getAppListScraper, GROSSING_COLUMN_INDEX);
  });
});

casper.run(function() {
  this.echo('Free Apps');
  printToConsole(this, free);
  writeToFile("freeTop500.json", JSON.stringify(free));

  this.echo('Paid Apps');
  printToConsole(this, paid);
  writeToFile("paidTop500.json", JSON.stringify(paid));

  this.echo('Grossing Apps');
  printToConsole(this, grossing);
  writeToFile("grossingTop500.json", JSON.stringify(grossing));

  this.exit();
});
```

Comment: I already proposed this scraper solution in an earlier edit, but I got down-voted. I think the original poster does not want to rely on 3rd parties for this data...

Comment: Yes your answer must stay, because it is certainly an option, even though you come to depend on a 3rd party, and if you need it for anything serious it may not be the best idea. According to Apple you must be able to retrieve the data yourself - see my updated answer.

Comment: Good effort, but this will not work for our purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I recently was faced with the same problem.
After joining the dots from many sites, my solution goes like this:

You will need this list for the genres:
https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/genre-mapping/

And this list for the country codes:
https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/linking-to-the-itunes-music-store/#Legacy

This link gives you a basic RSS overview and generator, but misses so much:
https://rss.itunes.apple.com/en-us

The next are examples I managed to piece together:

```
Top 100 Christian & Gospel
https://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topsongs/genre=22/explicit=true/limit=100/xml

Or, the same one with JSON results
https://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topsongs/genre=22/explicit=true/limit=100/json

Or, without the explicit songs:
https://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topsongs/genre=22/limit=100/json    

Top 100 CCM
https://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topalbums/genre=1094/explicit=true/limit=100/xml
```

Just change the genre id, and the country code.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/{country code}/rss/topalbums/genre={genre code}/explicit=true/limit=100/xml
```

Comment: super helpful. ty!